# How to change the "userPassword" attribute of active directory use java jndi ？

Tags: java, active-directory, jndi

Our system need to connect to AD for create user , change user password. I can create user success and I can change other attributes successful. But if I change the error of javax.naming.NoPermissionException .

update pwd function:

```
public boolean updateAdPasswordForStudent(Student student) {
        if (!studentExistOnAD(student)) {
            return createAdAccountForStudent(student);
        }

        try {

            ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
            mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("userPassword", student.getPassword()));


            ldapConnection.modifyAttributes("cn=" + student.getStudentNum() + baseDirectoryOfStudent, mods);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("Failed update AD password for student {}.", student.getStudentNum());
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: if change the “userPassword” attribute, I got the error 
 javax.naming.NoPermissionException

Comment: You don't have permission to change the user's password. This is not a programming problem. You need to bind to AD as a user that does have that permission.